Title of book series about overlapping tech/magic dimensions
What is the sf/fantasy book series called where an young man/boy from a tech dimension can travel to an overlapping magic dimension because his alter ego in that dimension was killed
The boy is involved in some kind of race, and Phillip K. Dick comes to mind as author, but is likely not.
1970-1980s

@ToddWilcox Interestingly enough I completely forgot that part. I would say my question is focusing more one the actual story, rather than how they were clothed ;) Perhaps the questions should be merged since I would never have found that answer searching for what I wrote above

This sounds like it could be the Apprentice Adept series by Piers Anthony.
The points that match:

What is the sf/fantasy book series called where an young man/boy

Check. Stile is the primary MC

from a tech dimension can travel to an overlapping magic dimension

Check.  Phaze and Photon are respectively Magic and Science dimensions

because his alter ego in that dimension was killed

Check.

The boy is involved in some kind of race,

Check. Stile becomes a political force in Phaze.  He also competes actively in the games/races in Photon.

and Phillip K. Dick comes to mind as author, but is likely not. 1970-1980s

Partial check. From 1980. But by Piers Anthony, not Philip K. Dick.
More details below:

Apprentice Adept is a heptalogy of fantasy and science fiction novels written by English American author Piers Anthony. The series takes place on Phaze and Proton, two worlds occupying the same space in two different dimensional planes. Phaze is a lush planet of magic, where Proton is a barren mining planet of science. As the series opens, each person born on Phaze and Proton has an alternate self living on the other world. But if a person on either world lacks a duplicate (for instance if a Proton citizen immigrated there from another planet, or a counterpart from the opposite frame died), he can cross to the other through an energy "curtain" that circumscribes each frame.
The first three books in the series follow Proton serf Stile as he enters Phaze and becomes an important political force there.


It was right next to Phillip K. Dick on my bookshelf. Thanks!

Great to hear you were able to find it.  Happy reading.  LoL

I mean, when I had them on my bookshelves in the '80s - which was why Phillip came to mind. I alas lost almost all my paperbacks in a flooded basement.
